# couldn't run (npm run dev) with laravel/ui

Tags: laravel, npm, npm-run, laravel-ui

I have created laravel application with the (laravel/Ui) package, and I have used bootstrap UI, everything working well, but when I rung (npm run dev) after (npm install), it is stuck like this:
PS E:\server\htdocs\me-online> npm run dev

```
> @ dev E:\server\htdocs\me-online
> vite

Port 3000 is in use, trying another one...

  vite v2.9.13 dev server running at:

  > Local: http://localhost:3001/
  > Network: use `--host` to expose

  ready in 357ms.


  Laravel v9.19.0 

  > APP_URL: http://localhost
```

I tried this also:

```
PS E:\server\htdocs\me-online> npm run dev -host 3004

> @ dev E:\server\htdocs\me-online
> vite "3004"

Port 3000 is in use, trying another one...

  vite v2.9.13 dev server running at:

  > Local: http://localhost:3001/
  > Network: use `--host` to expose

  ready in 292ms.

(!) Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions or html files and there are no explicit optimizeDeps.include patterns. Skipping dependency pre-bundling.
```

I have done this with many projects without any problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel UI is currently broken with Vite. Laravel team is working on it:

https://github.com/laravel/ui/pull/228